# How to add suffix at each line of large string

Tags: c#, string

I have written a code to add Suffix at end of each line of a multi-line String but code only appends at the end of string. I am beginner. Can somebody help me in clarifying where I am mistaken? Here is my code:

```
protected void Prefix_Suffix_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String txt_input = Input_id.InnerText.ToString().Trim();
    String txt_suffix = Suffix_id.InnerText.ToString().Trim();
    String txt_output = Output_id.InnerText.ToString().Trim();

    txt_input = txt_input.Replace(txt_suffix + "\n", "\n");
    txt_input = txt_input + txt_suffix;
    Output_id.InnerText = txt_input;
}
```

**Input:**

> Line1
>
> Line2
>
> Line3

**Desired output:**

> Line1AppededText
>
> Line2AppendedText
>
> Line3AppendedText

Comment: You just got the arguments mixed in up in the "Replace" function - check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2). The thing you want to replace goes first, then you put what you want to change it to second. Try `txt_input = txt_input.Replace("\n", txt_suffix + "\n");` instead. Demo (without syntax errors): https://dotnetfiddle.net/jnzgUy

Comment: what is suffix here? what are the values coming in `txt_input` and `txt_suffix`?

Comment: I think you mean 'prefix' instead of 'suffix'. Try `txt_input = txt_suffix + txt_input;`

Comment: Values are bound to textareas of html

Comment: See the update to my first comment above, it's a simple error

Comment: @Mikev look carefully, the arguments to Replace() are the wrong way round

Comment: @Mikev my point was it _doesn't_ work unless you swap the arguments in Replace. Not sure how you can say the code shown in the question "works" if it doesn't produce the intended output. It might not crash, but that's not the same as being correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let's `Split` text to lines, append each `line` and, finally, `Join` into `string` back:

```
  string source = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    "Line1",
    "Line2", 
    "Line3");

  // Let's have a look at the initial string; 
  Console.WriteLine(source);
  Console.WriteLine();

  string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, source
    .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(line => line + "AppendedText"));

  Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
Line1
Line2
Line3

Line1AppendedText
Line2AppendedText
Line3AppendedText
```

Answer (score 0):

The string of that comes out of your `Input_id.InnerText` is a string that consists of many lines. So if you want to append to each line, you need think of a way to treat those lines separately.

A line-end is denoted as the character '\n'. It looks like 2 characters to you, but the engine will treat it as one: line-end.

What you can do is split (break up) this string into multiple strings by snapping the string whenever you find a '\n'. You can do this by the following:

```
var lines = Input_id.InnerText.ToString().Split('\n');
```

Now `lines` contains an array of strings, each item in there containing a line of the input.

Now you could create a new string that will be built up by your split array as follows:

```
var newString = "";
foreach(var line in lines) {
    newString += line + "<appendText>\n"; //note how we add the \n again since those disappeared by splitting
}
```

Now `newString` will contain the new string with each line containing the appended text.

A way shorter answer would be to for instance use the replace function like this:

```
var newString = Input_id.InnerText.ToString().Replace("\n", "<AppendedText>\n");
```

There is many ways to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You just made a mistake when passing your values into the `Replace()` method. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2) for `String.Replace()` defines it like this:

> public string Replace (string oldValue, string newValue);

The first argument ("oldValue") should be the thing you want to replace. The second argument ("newValue") should be the thing you want to change it to. You've just got them the wrong way round. You're asking it to replace the new text (suffix and newline) with the old text (just the newline), which clearly it can't do because the suffix text doesn't exist in the string yet - and it wouldn't be logical even if it worked.

Change

```
txt_input = txt_input.Replace(txt_suffix + "\n", "\n");
```

to

```
txt_input = txt_input.Replace("\n", txt_suffix + "\n");
```

and you should be fine. As other answers alluded to, there may be nicer ways of achieving the same output, but in terms of fixing your original code this is all you should need to do.

Here's a live demo (just using console output instead of HTML elements): https://dotnetfiddle.net/jnzgUy

Comment: thanks for your time but it is adding suffix to every next line instead of appending at end of each line.

Comment: no, it doesn't - take a look at the demo. That's assuming that your input data is actually in the format I've assumed though. If the data doesn't look like that (in terms of where the newline characters occur) then you might have an issue.